# symfony2 security firewall pattern on windows

Tags: regex, windows, symfony, firewall

I noticed a strange behaviour in firewall pattern configuration in Symfony 2.3 in windows7.

Simply put, if I use this configuration:

```
support:
  pattern: /support/*
```

My route is recognized and security token put under the right firewall.

If I use a regexp configuration:

```
support:
  pattern: /support/.*
```

My route isn't recognized any more and security token does not exists.

How is this possible? .* shouldn't be the correct regexp?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid pattern with a start delimiter. Try something like this:

```
support:
    pattern:    
        ^/support/
```

Comment: start delimiter is not required to have a valid regex